# Stackoverflow on @PreUpdate

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I am getting a stackoverflow exception whenerver I am trying to use the @PreUpdate annotation on entity, which uses the Embedded Auditable Entity and @EntityListeners.

In my entity I am trying to fetch User data through a service, in order to update fields CreateBy/LastUpdateBy on my entity. I can't just simply put the String in it, I need the reference to User itself.

I already tried the approach with injecting the entity manager into the AuditListener and flushing it manually, but it doesn't work properly. Also, I tried to pass the User data in spring context instead of using a service, but since it keeps the static values, it has no use for me. I need to somehow fetch the User entity inside AuditListener, without going into an infinite loop.

Any ideas?

Here's stacktrace:

```html
2019-01-04 15:45:52 ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.StackOverflowError] with root cause
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
                at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
                at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
                at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
                at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
                at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
                at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
                at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
                at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
                at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
                at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
                at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:671)
                at com.app.server.repositories.impl.UserRepositoryImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d072e6d0.findByUsername(<generated>)
                at com.app.server.services.impl.UserServiceImpl.findUserByUsername(UserServiceImpl.java:131)
                at com.app.server.services.impl.UserServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$852b5ce2.invoke(<generated>)
                at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:667)
                at com.app.server.services.impl.UserServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$80381f41.findUserByUsername(<generated>)
                at com.app.server.defautmodel.audit.UserTimeAuditListener.setUpdatedOn(UserTimeAuditListener.java:37)
                at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor177.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
                at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.ListenerCallback.performCallback(ListenerCallback.java:35)
                at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.CallbackRegistryImpl.callback(CallbackRegistryImpl.java:97)
                at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.CallbackRegistryImpl.preUpdate(CallbackRegistryImpl.java:71)
                at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.invokeInterceptor(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:350)
                at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.handleInterception(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:332)
                at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.scheduleUpdate(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:283)
                at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:154)
                at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:235)
                at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:94)
                at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:44)
                at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1415)
                at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1501)
                at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1537)
                at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1505)
                at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:135)
                at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:74)
                at com.app.server.repositories.impl.UserRepositoryImpl.findByUsername(UserRepositoryImpl.java:40)
                at com.app.server.repositories.impl.UserRepositoryImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$46c3b507.invoke(<generated>)
                at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:736)
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
                at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
                at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
                at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
                at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:671)
                at com.app.server.repositories.impl.UserRepositoryImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d072e6d0.findByUsername(<generated>)
                at com.app.server.services.impl.UserServiceImpl.findUserByUsername(UserServiceImpl.java:131)
                at com.app.server.services.impl.UserServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$852b5ce2.invoke(<generated>)
                at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:667)
                at com.app.server.services.impl.UserServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$80381f41.findUserByUsername(<generated>)
                at com.app.server.defautmodel.audit.UserTimeAuditListener.setUpdatedOn(UserTimeAuditListener.java:37)
                at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor177.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
                at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.ListenerCallback.performCallback(ListenerCallback.java:35)
                at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.CallbackRegistryImpl.callback(CallbackRegistryImpl.java:97)
                at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.CallbackRegistryImpl.preUpdate(CallbackRegistryImpl.java:71)
                at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.invokeInterceptor(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:350)
                at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.handleInterception(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:332)
                at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.scheduleUpdate(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:283)
                at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:154)
                at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:235)
                at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:94)
                at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:44)
                at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1415)
                at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1501)
                at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1537)
                at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1505)
                at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:135)
                at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:74)
                at com.app.server.repositories.impl.UserRepositoryImpl.findByUsername(UserRepositoryImpl.java:40)
                at com.app.server.repositories.impl.UserRepositoryImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$46c3b507.invoke(<generated>)
                at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:736)
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
                at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
                at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
                at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
                at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:671)
                at com.app.server.repositories.impl.UserRepositoryImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d072e6d0.findByUsername(<generated>)
                at com.app.server.services.impl.UserServiceImpl.findUserByUsername(UserServiceImpl.java:131)
                at com.app.server.services.impl.UserServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$852b5ce2.invoke(<generated>)
                at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:667)
                at com.app.server.services.impl.UserServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$80381f41.findUserByUsername(<generated>)
                at com.app.server.defautmodel.audit.UserTimeAuditListener.setUpdatedOn(UserTimeAuditListener.java:37)
                at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor177.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
                at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.ListenerCallback.performCallback(ListenerCallback.java:35)
                at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.CallbackRegistryImpl.callback(CallbackRegistryImpl.java:97)
                at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.CallbackRegistryImpl.preUpdate(CallbackRegistryImpl.java:71)
                at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.invokeInterceptor(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:350)
                at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.handleInterception(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:332)
                at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.scheduleUpdate(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:283)
                at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:154)
                at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:235)
                at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:94)
                at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:44)
                at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1415)
                at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1501)
                at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1537)
                at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1505)
                at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:135)
                at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:74)
                at com.app.server.repositories.impl.UserRepositoryImpl.findByUsername(UserRepositoryImpl.java:40)
                at com.app.server.repositories.impl.UserRepositoryImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$46c3b507.invoke(<generated>)
                at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:736)
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
                at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
                at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
                at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
                at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:671)
                at com.app.server.repositories.impl.UserRepositoryImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d072e6d0.findByUsername(<generated>)
                at com.app.server.services.impl.UserServiceImpl.findUserByUsername(UserServiceImpl.java:131)
                at com.app.server.services.impl.UserServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$852b5ce2.invoke(<generated>)
                at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:667)
                at com.app.server.services.impl.UserServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$80381f41.findUserByUsername(<generated>)
                at com.app.server.defautmodel.audit.UserTimeAuditListener.setUpdatedOn(UserTimeAuditListener.java:37)
                at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor177.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
                at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.ListenerCallback.performCallback(ListenerCallback.java:35)
                at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.CallbackRegistryImpl.callback(CallbackRegistryImpl.java:97)
                at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.CallbackRegistryImpl.preUpdate(CallbackRegistryImpl.java:71)
                at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.invokeInterceptor(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:350)
                at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.handleInterception(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:332)
                at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.scheduleUpdate(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:283)
                at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:154)
                at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:235)
                at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:94)
                at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:44)
```

Comment: Can you show the code. Also the code of your UserDetailService.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default all transactions are `read/write`, and since you are using `@PreUpdate` it will always be triggered for all transactions because of the `FlushMode` on `read/write` transactions. In your case, if you want to bypass `@PreUpdate` in cases where you only fetch data you need to specify for your transaction to at least be `readOnly` this will create hiberbate session in `FlushMode.NEVER` therefore `@PreUpdate` will not be triggered. To be extra safe in case your transaction is embedded in pervios transaction so it will inherit its properties, you can use `Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW` which will suspend previous transaction execution, but be carefull with it since since this can cause performance issues in larger applications